# c# - Multidimensional Array position

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to make a program that reads input from a .txt file and it puts it in an array and then it reads a specific point in this arraylist.

Example:

Input:

```
99 20 30
28 3
10 31 29
```

Specific point in array:

```
array[1,1] = 3 <- I know that this is wrong, but this is where i wanna get.
```

I've tried to make an arraylist of arrays but i don't know how to get to that position.

Comment: you want to edit the value of this position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after the declaration you could do something like:

```
string[][] arr = new string[10][];

arr[1] = new string[10];
arr[1][1] = "3";
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of lists is another option, which should work well since lists are designed to be dynamic.  Here's a sample:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<List<string>> MyList = MakeList(@"C:\InFile.txt");
        MessageBox.Show(MyList[1][1]);
    }
    public List<List<string>> MakeList(string Path)
    {
        List<List<string>> TempList = new List<List<string>>();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path);
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string Temp = sr.ReadLine();
            TempList.Add(Temp.Split().ToList<string>());
        }
        return TempList;
    }
```